# Json based geotargeting

Tags: javascript, json

Is this correct? I suspect there is an error somewhere in the middle on line 12 when trying to separate the two countries

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script> 



<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>

$.getJSON( "http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?", function(data){

// traffic aus deutschland wird redirected, z.b. nach ...
if (data.countryCode == "CA") { 
window.location = 'canada.php';
} ,

if (data.countryCode == "AU") { 
window.location = 'australia.php';
} 

else {
// traffic aus anderen ländern wird redirected, z.b. nach ...
window.location = 'what.php';
}

})
 </SCRIPT>`
```

Comment: Remove comma after: `window.location = 'canada.php';
} ,`

Answer (score 0):

remove the comma between the if statements

also you might want to write it like

```
if () {
} else if () {
}
else () {
}
```

Comment: I wrote the answer on the phone hence the lack of conditions